# The property ETag not found in Document Db result returned using FeedResponse<Dynamic>

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have two simple queries, one returns Single Result using Id

```
Document doc = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(entity.CollectionSelfLink,
                    new FeedOptions()
                    {
                        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(entity.PartitionKey),
                    }).Where(d => d.Id == entity.Id).AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

once I have the document, I simply call `doc.ETag` and it provides the ETag.

Next, I use the `FeedResponse<dynamic>` to get few results.

```
IDocumentQuery<Document> queryList = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(collectionSelfLink, (SqlQuerySpec)query, new FeedOptions
            {
                PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(partitionKey),
                MaxItemCount = 10,
                RequestContinuation = requestContinuation,
            }).AsDocumentQuery();

            if (queryList.HasMoreResults)
            {
                FeedResponse<T> feed = await queryList.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
                IList<T> documents = feed.ToList();
            }
```

Now, If I use the same `doc.ETag` I get the following error: That ETag is not found and it through DocumentDbException

```
oft.Azure.Documents.QueryResult.GetProperty(String propertyName, Type returnType)\r\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)\r\n
```

The Documents returned by the SingleEntity and Query is exactly the same. Any thoughts what would cause this difference?

Answer (score 0):

This line `FeedResponse<T> feed = await queryList.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();` should be `FeedResponse<Document> feed = await queryList.ExecuteNextAsync<Document>();`